# thickbox and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, thickbox

I have a little problem that I just can't figure out. I'd like to post data to server (php) and then after processing display the result with thickbox iframe.

I looked at ajax example from thickbox, but there's no passing, processing and returning at the same time.  The basic example works for me.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Newman

Comment: Do you mean Fancybox? ThickBox was ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read this part?

> Description: Use a hidden HTTP request
>   (AJAX) to fetch files from the same
>   server and have ThickBox display the
>   contents of the files. Instructions:
>   Create a link element () Give
>   the link a class attribute with a
>   value of thickbox (class="thickbox")
>   Provide a path in the href to the
>   file/directory on the server.
>   (href="ajaxLogin.htm") In the href
>   attribute, after the URL path to the
>   file, add the following query on to
>   the end of the URL:
>   ?height=300&width=300 Change the
>   values of height and width in the
>   query accordingly Optionally you may
>   add modal=true to the query string
>   (e.g.
>   ?height=300&width=300&modal=true) so
>   that closing a ThickBox will require
>   calling the tb_remove() function from
>   within the ThickBox. See the login
>   example, where you must click cancel
>   to close the ThickBox. Important to
>   Remember: In order to open new Ajax
>   content in an open Ajax ThickBox, its
>   code must also contain the appropriate
>   HTML (class=""thickbox) to launch an
>   Ajax ThickBox (see demo for example).
>   The only catch is, the ThickBox calls
>   must include both the width and height
>   of the original ThickBox. If you leave
>   it blank the window will resize to the
>   default size(630x440).

The example and it's description make sense. You are not preforming the AJAX request - ThickBox does that based on the href value of the link with the class ThickBox, and loads that data into the resulting ThickBox.

Comment: Yes, but how do I pass data to php?

Comment: Because this is a link, the only data you can pass is GET data, so in the link's href you would put `myLoadedInData.php?name=John`, and in the PHP script you could get that value by doing `echo $_GET["name"];`.

Comment: Thanks!!! That works. I was actually thinking if there was I way to run $.post and then display data returned in iframe, but I'll use this instead!

Comment: No problem. ;) Check my answer too.

Comment: Just one thing. What if I want to pass data that  I received from user input? How can I change href dynamically?

Comment: HTML: `<a href="#" class="thickbox" id="dyn_link">This is my dynamic Thickbox link!</a>` jQuery: `vars = "name=John"; $("#dyn_link").attr("href", "myLoadedInData.php?"+vars);` Like so.